# Macbook pro hard drive not recognized by any means after using chkdsk /r on bootcamp

Tags: hard-drive, macbook, boot-camp, chkdsk, boot-partition

Good afternoon everyone,

Here is my headache:

I have (had?) a macbook pro late 2011 wtih bootcamp running in Win 7, the bootcamp partition started to give problems (corrupted data I recon) so I tried running several programs (HD regenerator, windows 7 installing CD for repairing, Knoppix 7, testdisk, stellar data recovery, mac utility disk...etc,etc...) but most of them didn´t work since Macbooks dont have BIOS therefore couldn´t access the bootcamp partition.

After trying many things, I read in a blog that using chkdsk /r from command might fix the problem, so its what I did, run chksdk /r and wait.

After waiting about 6hours it was still at 40% and it seemed to be hang at that point so I thouhg best thing was to restart (happy ideas at 3am in the morning).

To my surprise it would never restart again, not in MacOS, neither in bootcamp, instead I had the interrogation mark while booting the macbook pro.

Then I took out the harddrive and replace it for a new one, I have old corrupted/not recognized hard drive in a an external drive now.

Question is: What can I do to fix it/make it recognizable and save my old data?

Thank you very much, I´ve been going crazy for a month now and I can´t find any answers in the net.

Comment: First question is, do you have another computer you can hook the old/bad drive up to?